# TypeScript: how to make a property conditional from an existing type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, type-conversion

So let's say I have

```
type Link = {
  text: string;
  link: string;
}

interface BigLink extends Link {
  some: number;
  something: string;
  else: string;
}
```

but I have a variable that shares all these properties except that the link property can be optional.
I don't want to create a whole new type just to change one field to `link?: string`.
Is there a way to do something like

```
type OptionalBigLink = BigLink & { link?: string }
```

so that I can overwrite the link field and make it optional.
^ The above code still throws an error when I don't pass in the link property.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

```
type OptionalBigLink = Partial<Pick<BigLink, "link">> & Omit<BigLink, "link">;
```

Some tests in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=49&ssc=2&pln=15&pc=1#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQC0gADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRonzFBTBPB3AERcwABS0%20mM9ysygc9wASmCKhwzQ8ZC8iHFzmB7BoXzcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiQ58D0Ii8fLpDKZgj5SWxfPADlQAHJhAA5SASPlBFQAeS%20ZHegmdWkgR1QjgUrmkeFATjNOmGWH0KAQiGhwkuNok4uiIgMHGxCyYrA4PCCJVQ7VAzwyiV5AG9FABIBSrVD5K6oSicZgAbinboS86pS9XigAvmvFBkFGRkgwlgAhCjMYcJcGzlHcYS3xITyey5DzzjsRDSb5r98kBzOJmC3RdhgAmBMzAnc1z3YIByIUBk2oBpOAYaArxvEceTofN2WgAAeWh3UIrCX34PkN3iPkAD5aNAAAyZDEHkMjrwo-lqLotcVAAPQAfnJRoqTQfQ52Q1DGgw8icPHKcZwkvkFCpPleCnD9IHnAAGdTAOQIZl3nPlNLUqcoK0-lTPU%20DpRE61xIAJnnFD6mkzCOLk0A30U4yVNQMz9Ms3SNKAwzQKsoDAos4zrPXEdjO4-dhMpByqQAZhcqT0I87C73koKdL0zTwtiqK9JiyLkEC6jEpHKU9yAA)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Omit` to remove the property from `BigLink` and then do the intersection.

```
type OptionalBigLink = Omit<BigLink, "link"> & { link?: string }
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly as well - might be easier to use for my case since link is a simple scalar type.